# Обработка исключений (вывод сообщения на экран)

Tags: c++, исключения, обработка-ошибок

Есть класс для обработки исключений

```
class VException : public std::exception 
{  
    std::string name;  
public:  
    VException();  
    VException(std::string);  
    VException(std::string, std::exception&);  

    std::string get_name() const;  
};
```

И при срабатывании исключения в main программа падает с сообщением `terminate called after throwing an instance of 'char const*'`
Понятно, что это проблема при приведении `std::string` к `char const*`, но не понятно как ее обойти.

```
Vector<int>* v;
Vector<int>* v1;

try
{
    v = new Vector<int>;
    v1 = new Vector<int>(5);
}
catch(VException& ex)
{
    std::cout << ex.get_name() << std::endl;
}

try
{
    v->pop_back(); // тут срабатывает исключение удаления из пустого вектора  
}
catch(VException& ex)
{
    std::cout << ex.get_name().c_str() << std::endl;
}
```

Comment: не знаю, что Вам понятно, т.к. мне не понятно ничего. Покажите Ваш `throw`

Comment: Вангую что вы написали `throw "Ошибка"`. Тип исключения получился `const char *`, и не был пойман ни одним обработчиком.

Answer (score -1):

Обработка исключений - достаточно тонкий процесс, и тащить туда std::string - создавать себе проблемы.

Дело в том, что исключение может выпрыгнуть и из std::string, и что вы тогда будете делать?

Откажитесь от использования STL - контейнеров и динамической памяти при обработке исключений.

Comment: А почему может `std::string` кинуть исключение? Когда ответите на это вопрос, ответьте и на другой: что в этом случае Вы сможете сделать с системой?

Comment: @ixSci когда вы прямо сформулируете свое пожелание относительно моего ответа, я потрачу свое время на внесение исправлений. Ребусами я не занимаюсь.

Comment: Да это не ребус, я всего лишь пытался Вам указать на абсурдность совета, не использовать `std::string`(и другие динамические контейнеры) в классах-исключениях. Это одна из баек, которая давно ходит в интернетах, в которой смысла почти 0.

Comment: @ixSci других аргументов у вас нет? Ссылки на примеры, исходники? 
Пример вылета исключения из std::string - легко, сделайте at() за пределами строки и наслаждайтесь. А программист всего лишь хотел красиво отформатировать вывод.

Comment: ага, т.е. `[]` за пределами C-строки это будет нормально? Не совсем понял каких аргументов Вы от меня ждёте и каких исходников. Понимаете, Вы выдвигаете тезис, что использование динамических контейнеров в классах-исключениях может привести к проблемам, я с этим не спорю, я лишь утверждаю, что эти проблемы иррелевантны, т.к. их решить в принципе нельзя в 99.999% случаев, поэтому можно смело использовать такие контейнеры в классах-исключениях.

Comment: @ixSci зависит от культуры кодирования, только и всего. Если культуры недостаточно, возникают "нерешаемые" проблемы.

Comment: Поделитесь рецептом решения `std::bad_alloc`?

Comment: Давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/45904/discussion-between-gbg-and-ixsci).